# Writing a list including integers and strings to a file in Python

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have a real stickler of a dilemma I need y'all to solve.

I need quantities my program to write a list of products and quantities to a text file.

I've gotten this far:

```
file = open("Orders.txt", "w")
file.write("Stock we require \n")
file.write("Chips Needed:")
file.write(str(order1))
file.write("\n")
file.write("Juice Needed:")
file.write(str(order2))
file.close()
```

order1 and order2 are integers

This is what this code produces in the Orders.txt:

```
Stock we require
Chips Needed:39Juice Needed:0
```

(Where order1 was 39 and order2 was 0)

I want:

```
Stock we require:

Chips
(order1)

Juice
(order2)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post what you have tried so far, including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.format`:

```
with open("Orders.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("Stock we require:\n")
    file.write("Chips ({})\n".format(order1))
    file.write("Juice ({})\n".format(order2))
```

You can easily change the format this way.

Also note the usage of `with`.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you may consider `file.writelines(line1,line2,...)`